# Check if a thread is running recursively?

Tags: c#

I've a main thread called t1:

```
Thread t1 => new Thread(UpdateResults);
```

that execute a method called `UpdateResult` this method require internet connection. Now sometimes the connection could be broken.

When the connection is down, the method `UpdateResult` return an exception and the thread `t1` terminate the execution.

I need to execute again the thread `t1` so I though to create another thread `t2` that check recursively if the thread `t1` is running or no.

Both thread are started automatically. This is the code of thread `t2` method:

```
while (true)
{
    if (!t1.IsAlive)
    {
       t1.Start();
    }
}
```

this code unfortuntely slow down the app UI, 'cause is an infinite loop.
What I can do instead for fix this?

Comment: Wrap `UpdateResults` in a `try..catch` block?

Comment: @BlackBear is already in a try catch block, but the thread terminate the execution if an exception is trown

Comment: I'd say to have `updateresults` do the re-try / connect, not the thread. The thread should just be where the work is done, not a tester to know if it was done, I think.

Comment: @AgainMe If you catch the exception, then nothing is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of wasting another thread `t2` just to watch `t1`, you may consider to change the method of thread `t1`:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(o =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateResult();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // do some error handling
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
});
```

So you catch the exception (*without rethrowing it!*) and prevent the crash of the whole thread.

This is of course only a simple example. You should try to catch only the specific exception for a broken connection and add proper error handling (e.g. logging etc.).
And adjust the time the thread should sleep according to your needs.

Comment: I really like this solution, seems working fine in code. Thanks to all ;)

Answer (score 2):

One approach to avoid an infinite polling is to `Join` the thread, and re-spawn it when it stops:

```
while (true) {
    t1.Join();
    t1 = ... // Make a replacement thread
    t1.Start();
}
```

It goes without saying that this should not be done from UI thread, because `Join()` blocks indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with your architecture, something as simple as waiting a second in each loop of Thread t2 would massively improve performance.

```
while (true)
{
    if(!t1.isAlive)
    {
        t1.Start();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

(You can adjust the time to anything that makes sense in your context.)

Though instead of this multi-thread solution, i would ask: why does thread t1 terminate because of an Exception? You can catch it with a `try`-`catch` block.

Instead of `UpdateResults` call `SafeUpdateResults` which just says:

```
void SafeUpdateResults()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try { UpdateResults(); }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //track the Error if you want
            Console.WriteLine("t1-Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I would even recommend, going into the function `UpdateResults()` and catching the Exception right where it happens, and then reacting accordingly (though this here is arguably easier).

Comment: alas my humble quest for reputation was thwarted once again by faster posters.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: Thanks ^^ and some redundancy never hurts.